# Check if android sdk 33 clipboard is enabled

Tags: android, clipboard, android-13

Is it possible to check if the clipboard widget on android sdk 33 is enabled/disabled? The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/copy-paste#duplicate-notifications) says to check the sdk version and show a snackbar/toast if <33, but what if the clipboard widget is disabled from the settings and we want to show information that the text was copied?

Answer (score 0):

clipboard widget is ALWAYS visible on Android 13, there is nothing to check. I don't see any option for disabling this popup (there is a toggle for disabling `Toast` when app gets access to clipboard, e.g. when pasting copied text, thats different case)